# What is purpose of T4 Generator in T4toolbox

Tags: t4, t4-toolbox

I am using T4toolbox, I am confused what the generator is for. I can run the following

```
public class Generator1 : Generator
{

    protected override void RunCore()
    {

        Template1 t = new Template1();
        t.Output.File = "t3.txt";
        t.Render();

    }
}
```

or I can run t4 script directly like the following.

```
Template1 t = new Template1();

t.Output.File = "t3.txt";

t.Render();
```

But I can do the same using t4 script without generator as well.
So I mean can do the same thing with two approach "script --> generator --> template" and "script --> template", am I missing something?

Comment: What is t4? Your code looks like C#.. I'm confused.

Comment: @Earlz: T4 is a code generator for .NET built into Visual Studio 2008+.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Generator class is useful when want to encapsulate multiple templates. More here: http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creating-complex-code-generators/

Comment: Take a look at the code examples Oleg provides as well. It demonstrates pretty well how to use them.